# Alexa Skill Language

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Is there any possibility to switch the language for skills? It seems to me that alexa directly uses german as well as english but using alexa over a skill, english is the preferred language. So slots are not beeing recognized properly

Answer (score 1):

When you create a skill you can choose a "default language" next to your "Skill name".
When your skill is already created you can set the Availability of your skill.

Maybe your device itself is not configured to the correct language?

Did you try the "Alexa Simulator" in the developer console? There you can change the language as well to test your skill.
You should have a look in the JSON Input what is written for "locale".

Here are some more details: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add language from your build screen > language settings and also sample utterance for a particular language and you can test different language by test > change language.